# Display Image after drag and drop on html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I am implementing Drag and Drop Images Control using JQuery/JS. What has been accomplished is that user drag some image file and drop into html page. After dropping file, I only show filename and its size.

What I need to display image on the page as well. But I am not able to get image file content in jquery.

Following is code which i have written:

```
function handleFileUpload(files, obj) {
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', files[i]);

    var status = new createStatusbar(obj); //Using this we can set progress.
    status.setFileNameSize(files[i].name, files[i].size);
    sendFileToServer(fd, status);

}
}
$(document).ready(function () {
var obj = $("#dragandrophandler");
obj.on('dragenter', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('border', '2px solid #0B85A1');
});
obj.on('dragover', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
obj.on('drop', function (e) {

    $(this).css('border', '2px dotted #0B85A1');
    e.preventDefault();
    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;

    //We need to send dropped files to Server
    handleFileUpload(files, obj);
});
$(document).on('dragenter', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
$(document).on('dragover', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    obj.css('border', '2px dotted #0B85A1');
});
$(document).on('drop', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});

});
```

On debugging function `handleFileUpload`, it only displays following attributes:

[image]

Can you help in this regard?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, here is how I resolved the issue:

```
function handleFileUpload(files, obj) {
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', files[i]);
    var status = new createStatusbar(obj); //Using this we can set progress.
    //status.setFileNameSize(files[i].name, files[i].size);
    //sendFileToServer(fd, status);

    var list = document.getElementById("image-list");
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.classList.add("obj");
    img.file = files[i];
    cell.setAttribute("align", "center");
    cell.setAttribute("valign", "bottom");
    cell.appendChild(img);
    list.appendChild(cell);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function (aImg) { return function (e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: This worked for me.

The key is that you can set img.src programmatically to be the data returned by the load event.  Thanks!

Comment: wow that black magic reader.onload =  line.. :D i failed to convert it to modern syntax :D but works!

Answer (score 10):

I haven't tried it out, but you're making use of the [HTML5 File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). Your image is an instantiation of the `File` class, which itself is a subclass of `Blob`. Using the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) you can access the file's contents. This article over at the MDN links to another article in the network which shows how to use it: [Showing thumbnails of User-selected images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images)

Basically, you access the contents like so:

```
function handleFileUpload( files, obj ) {
    for( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
        // ... your other code
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(){
            // Should look like data:,<jibberish_data> based on which method you called
            console.log(reader.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
    }
}
```